# NSString transition between UIViews

Tags: objective-c, xcode, nsstring

I want to use `NSString` from one `UIView` in another `UIView`.

There are two ways how I create `NSString` in the first `UIView`.

```
NSString *firstNameTemp =  [[[[html componentsSeparatedByString:@"<first_name>"] objectAtIndex:1] componentsSeparatedByString:@"</first_name>"] objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *lastNameTemp =  @"Михаил";
```

If I use `NSLog` i get same lines in both cases:

```
2012-06-15 16:21:54.778 VKLike[22718:707] –Ь–Є—Е–∞–Є–ї
2012-06-15 16:21:54.790 VKLike[22718:707] –Ь–Є—Е–∞–Є–ї
```

There is an issue with encoding, but if I create `UILabel` with `NSString` it shows correct string (Михаил).

In second `UIView` if use method

```
- (void) initPhotoViewWithFrame:(CGRect)frame Image:(UIImage *)image Name:(NSString *)name;
```

When I try to use ***firstNameTemp*** I get an Error.

But I get no Error if I use ***lastNameTemp***.

The question is: How to successfully pass the first `NSString` (***firstNameTemp***)?

Comment: As it shows correct string  in label then pass yourlable.text (it is also string ) to another view.

Comment: That's the most undesirable way. Because in first UIView I have only UIWebView

Comment: >> There is an issue with encoding, but if I create UILabel with NSString it shows correct string (Михаил).  -- take a look on my question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10950805/debugger-console-encoding-in-xcode-is-broken -- hope it helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a memory management error. You have to retain `firstNameTemp` (and later release it). Strictly, this is also true for `lastNameTemp` but the bug doesn't surface because string literals (`@"..."`) are created by the compiler and live as long as the process lives.

Comment: Great! It works! One more question: should I release it in initPhotoViewWithFrame method or in first UIView dealloc?