# hello.go:1:1: illegal character U+0023

Tags: go

I'm trying to run the hello world from golang [in this link](https://golang.org/doc/code.html)
But when I run go install, I'm getting this error:

```
hello.go:1:1: illegal character U+0023
```

This is my hello.go

```
package main    
import "fmt"
func main() {
  fmt.Printf("hello, world")
}
```

I'm using Mac OS El Captain
What is wrong?

Comment: You have a '#' somewhere in your code which is invalid.

Comment: Use this link to verify your terminal's UTF-8 settings http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4606570/os-x-terminal-utf-8-issues

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you have '#' in first line of your code which is invalid,
see this test sample code:

```
# just remove this line
package main

import "fmt" 

func main() {
    fmt.Println("Hello World!") 
}
```

this will give this error:

```
hello.go:1:1: illegal character U+0023 '#'
```

but if you remove lines containing `#` it works fine:

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    fmt.Println("Hello World!")
}
```

it seems your IDE is not for Go. See:
https://github.com/visualfc/liteide
https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/IDEsAndTextEditorPlugins
http://www.distilnetworks.com/setup-go-golang-ide-for-mac-os-x/

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem but had no '#' in the source whatsoever. My LOCALE was set correctly. My problem was that I created the source via cut and paste from:

https://medium.com/@singh.shreya8/how-to-install-go-lang-in-ubuntu-14-04-ubuntu-16-04-ubuntu-18-04-linux-19e4c8aad4b8

The problem was solved by deleting and retyping the double quotes in the source. Just for grins I tried a cut and paste from:

https://golang.org/doc/code.html

and had no problems. Go figure.