# How do I make my scanner accept "ÆØÅ", instead of returning a question mark in java?

Tags: java, visual-studio-code, utf-8, java.util.scanner

I am trying to input the letters `ÆØÅ` in a program I am currently writing.
I am using the `java.util.Scanner` to do this, however, it does not want to accept these characters mentioned above.

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in); <br>
String input = in.nextLine(); //Inputting testÆØÅ
```

Code runs as if nothing is broken, however, when debugging, a diamond square appears with a question mark inside it, for every "foreign" letter. Furthermore using VS code.

Also, when adding the scanner to my watchlist and seeing its properties, there is a field named Digits which has this value: `"0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"`.
How do I fix this, making my scanner accept `ÆØÅ`?
[image: Not working with scanner.]

[image: Working with JOptionPane and its showInputDialog]

[image]

Comment: Install (and select) a different font in VScode. That is nothing more than a missing glyph in your current font.

Comment: It is working fine in my terminal.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4606570/os-x-terminal-utf-8-issues

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Tried it, and it did not work. Still the same quiestion marks appears. Could have something to do with a delimiter?

Comment: @xdeepakv Couldn't get this to work either, seems different since it's on mac...

Comment: @ErikSkjellevik **No**. The code is fine. It's your font. You need a font that has your Swedish characters. Without that, it can't draw them. So you get a box and question marks. [Picture is worth 1000 words (apparently)](https://i.imgur.com/kArXc6l.png).

Comment: @ElliottFrisch It works fine when using JOptionPane though - if it was the font, then surely JOptionPane shouldn't be working?

Comment: @ErikSkjellevik Different font in JOptionPane (the Java font) than the VSCode terminal window (the console font controlled by VSCode).

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Cant seem to get it to work. Just installed a new font, Ubuntu Mono, which has ÆØÅ (shows me when asking if I want to install), however the scanner does not accept ÆØÅ. And furthermore the terminal looks broken with this font:)

Comment: @ErikSkjellevik I added the `visual-studio-code` tag to attract a wider audience, since this seems to be an environment issue rather than a Java issue.