# Visual Studio 2020 for mac puts a space after characters like á,é,ó. How can I fix this?

Tags: c#, macos, visual-studio

First time mac user and beginner in programming, sorry if the answer is obvious. The issue is in the console terminal not in the actual code:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/niFPi.jpg)

Im guessing it gets confused, because they aren't usual english characters, but I don't know where to change it to support them.

Comment: Wheer do you see a space after the accented characters? I cannot see it in the screenshot.

Comment: After I run the code in the terminal.

Comment: That's really not clear from your question. Maybe you should [edit] it and show how the console output looks like.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4606570/os-x-terminal-utf-8-issues

Comment: A screenshot of your IDE is not helpful when what you are concerned about is output in terminal.  Also, as noted previously, this is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4606570/os-x-terminal-utf-8-issues and you should find a solution there.  It's not a bad question :)

Answer (score 0):

*This* might help:

1. Go to Terminal -> Preferences -> Advanced (Tab) go down to International and select Unicode (UTF-8) as Character Encoding.
2. Tick Set locale environment variables on startup.

Comment: Sadly it didn't. Thanks for the help tho.